# How to use Pattern, Matcher in Java regex API to remove a specific line

Tags: java, string, qregularexpression

I have a complicate string split, I need to remove the *comments*, *spaces*, and keep all the *numbers* but change all  *string* into *character*. If the `-` sign is at the start and followed by a number, treat it as a negative number rather than a operator

the comment has the style of `?<space>comments<space>?` (the comments is a place holder)

Input :

```
-122+2 ? comments ?sa b
-122+2 ? blabla ?sa b
```

output :

```
 ["-122","+","2","?","s","a","b"]
```

(all string into character and no space, no comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace the unwanted string `\s*\?\s*\w+\s*(?=\?)` with `""`. You can chain `String#replaceAll` to remove any remaining whitespace. Note that `?=` means [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and here it means `\s*\?\s*\w+\s*` followed by a `?`. I hope you already know that `\s` specifies whitespace and `\w` specifies a word character.
2. Then you can use the regex, `^-\d+|\d+|\D` which means either negative integer in the beginning (i.e. `^-\d+`) or digits (i.e. `\d+`) or a non-digit (`\D`).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "-122+2 ? comments ?sa b";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\s*\\?\\s*\\w+\\s*(?=\\?)", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^-\\d+|\\d+|\\D");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-122
+
2
?
s
a
b
```

Comment: I didn't describe it properly, the comment is a place holder, it could be any string

Comment: Thanks so much, I'v learn so much about regular expression today, I wish you a nice evening, good night Arvind